# DCOM permissions error when exec from PHP but when executed from cmd works properly (officetopdf.exe)

Tags: php, windows, permissions, exec, dcom

I want a php script to execute a command `officetopdf.exe input.doc output.pdf` where `officetopdf.exe` is an program that uses the installed Office to export office files to pdf.

When executed it throws the error:

> ‘Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005 Access is denied.’

and does not execute properly.

- The server has IIS and Plesk panel. The user that calls PHP has been created with Plesk.
- When `officetopdf.exe` is executed directly with `cmd.exe` it works well as expected.
- It seems to be a problem of permissions of DCOM.
- On local environment on our office in another computer with Windows 8 changing DCOM permissions it worked well.
- On first install of office in the server all DCOM applications do not appear in DCOM config panel. I don't remember how we added but it wasn't automatically added because the Office was 32 bit and the system is 64 bit. If office 32 bit is installed the error 'Retrieving the COM class factory' changes to something like it does not find the class.
- Tested on 2 servers with Windows 2012

Comment: Could you share some code please?

Comment: Hi thanks! Well the code is very simple if you echo the exec('officetopdf.exe input.doc output.pdf') it throws the error described. It's a dcom permission problem but we can't figure it out.

Comment: Did you found a solution? Have the same problem. What was the DCOM setting on the Windows 8 computer?

Comment: Hi! At the end we manage to make it work using wamp and not IIS and changing DCOM permissions. The issue was with IIS.